# Bundler spits errors from other projects and Gemfiles

Tags: ruby, bundler, rbenv

I'm using bundler to handle the gems for multiple projects.

- bundler v 1.5.2
- Mac OS X
- rbenv with ruby 2.0

When I run `bundle install` for some reason it spits out errors from other Gemfiles that I've run previously, but have nothing to do with the folder and Gemfile I'm bundling.

Any idea what causes this?

```
MacBook-Pro:test mylo$ bundle install 
Using mini_portile (0.5.2) 
Using nokogiri (1.6.1) 
Using rack (1.5.2) 
Using rack-protection (1.5.2)
Using tilt (1.4.1) 
Using sinatra (1.4.4) 
Using bundler (1.5.2) 
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled
gem is installed. rbenv: version `.DS_Store' is not installed
/Users/mylo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5./lib/bundler/resolver.rb:134:in
`block in resolve': Could not find gem 'dii_eris (    = 2.0.3) ruby',
which is required by gem 'dii_pluto (    = 0) ruby', in any of the
sources. (Bundler::VersionConflict)     from
/Users/mylo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/safe_catch.rb:32:in
`catch'     from
/Users/mylo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5./lib/bundler/safe_catch.rb:32:in
`safe_catch'    from
/Users/mylo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5./lib/bundler/resolver.rb:132:in
`resolve'   from
/Users/mylo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:203:in
`resolve'   from
/Users/mylo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:133:in
 `specs'    from
 /Users/mylo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/environment.rb:22:in
 `specs'    from
 /Users/mylo/.rbenv/plugins/bundler/etc/rbenv.d/bundler/rehash.rb:115:in
 `gemspecs'     from
 /Users/mylo/.rbenv/plugins/bundler/etc/rbenv.d/bundler/rehash.rb:204:in
 `block (3 levels) in rehash'   from
 /Users/mylo/.rbenv/plugins/bundler/etc/rbenv.d/bundler/rehash.rb:203:in
 `open'     from
 /Users/mylo/.rbenv/plugins/bundler/etc/rbenv.d/bundler/rehash.rb:203:in
 `open'     from
 /Users/mylo/.rbenv/plugins/bundler/etc/rbenv.d/bundler/rehash.rb:203:in
 `block (2 levels) in rehash'   from
 /Users/mylo/.rbenv/plugins/bundler/etc/rbenv.d/bundler/rehash.rb:186:in
 `each'     from
 /Users/mylo/.rbenv/plugins/bundler/etc/rbenv.d/bundler/rehash.rb:186:in
 `block in rehash'  from
 /Users/mylo/.rbenv/plugins/bundler/etc/rbenv.d/bundler/rehash.rb:185:in
 `open'     from
 /Users/mylo/.rbenv/plugins/bundler/etc/rbenv.d/bundler/rehash.rb:185:in
 `open'     from
 /Users/mylo/.rbenv/plugins/bundler/etc/rbenv.d/bundler/rehash.rb:185:in
 `rehash'   from
 /Users/mylo/.rbenv/plugins/bundler/etc/rbenv.d/bundler/rehash.rb:462:in
 `<main    '
 /Users/mylo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler.rb:387:in
 `rescue in eval_gemspec': There was a NameError while loading
 codeproject.gemspec:  (Bundler::GemspecError) uninitialized constant
 Dii::Gemini from  
 /Users/mylo/gitcode/libs/codeproject/codeproject.gemspec:7:in `block
 in <main    '  from
 /Users/mylo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler.rb:376:in
 `eval_gemspec'     from
 /Users/mylo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler.rb:347:in
 `block in load_gemspec_uncached'   from
 /Users/mylo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:52:in
 `chdir'    from
 /Users/mylo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:52:in
 `chdir'    from
 /Users/mylo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler.rb:342:in
 `load_gemspec_uncached'    from
 /Users/mylo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler.rb:332:in
 `load_gemspec'     from
 /Users/mylo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:51:in
 `gemspec'  from /Users/mylo/gitcode/libs/codeproject/Gemfile:4:in
 `eval_gemfile'     from
 /Users/mylo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:30:in
 `instance_eval'    from
 /Users/mylo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:30:in
 `eval_gemfile'     from
 /Users/mylo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:9:in
 `evaluate'     from
 /Users/mylo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:26:in
 `build'    from
 /Users/mylo/.rbenv/plugins/bundler/etc/rbenv.d/bundler/rehash.rb:95:in
 `gemspecs'     from
 /Users/mylo/.rbenv/plugins/bundler/etc/rbenv.d/bundler/rehash.rb:204:in
 `block (3 levels) in rehash'   from
 /Users/mylo/.rbenv/plugins/bundler/etc/rbenv.d/bundler/rehash.rb:203:in
 `open'     from
 /Users/mylo/.rbenv/plugins/bundler/etc/rbenv.d/bundler/rehash.rb:203:in
 `open'     from
 /Users/mylo/.rbenv/plugins/bundler/etc/rbenv.d/bundler/rehash.rb:203:in
 `block (2 levels) in rehash'   from
 /Users/mylo/.rbenv/plugins/bundler/etc/rbenv.d/bundler/rehash.rb:186:in
 `each'     from
 /Users/mylo/.rbenv/plugins/bundler/etc/rbenv.d/bundler/rehash.rb:186:in
 `block in rehash'  from
 /Users/mylo/.rbenv/plugins/bundler/etc/rbenv.d/bundler/rehash.rb:185:in
 `open'     from
 /Users/mylo/.rbenv/plugins/bundler/etc/rbenv.d/bundler/rehash.rb:185:in
 `open'     from
 /Users/mylo/.rbenv/plugins/bundler/etc/rbenv.d/bundler/rehash.rb:185:in
 `rehash'   from
 /Users/mylo/.rbenv/plugins/bundler/etc/rbenv.d/bundler/rehash.rb:462:in
 `<main    '
```

Comment: I have the same issue, but if I run ```bundle```, which is supposed to be the same, I don't have these issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had a hunch that it probably had to do with *rbenv-bundler*, as indicated in [this issue](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/issues/322). But checking `gem list rbenv-bundler` didn't reveal the vilain. Until I tried `brew list | grep rbenv` as descrived [here](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/issues/588).

I simply did `brew uninstall rbenv-bundler` and all the problems described above seem to be gone! Also the `` rbenv: version `.DS_Store' is not installed `` you had in your dump seems to be gone.